# Childhood savings account closed years ago due to parents negligence. Can I reclaim it?

Tags: banking, savings, savings-account

Years ago, my parents received notice that my savings account was being closed. I was too young to do anything myself, and I guess my parents too lazy. There was only about $130 dollars in the account. Is it possible in the state of Nebraska to reclaim this account? Will their be anything even left in it?

(I've tried asking elsewhere and can't get anything, I don't know this site well or if this is the type of question accepted here. Sorry)

Comment: Try asking the bank where the account used to be. Chances are slim thou I reckon.

Answer (score 2):

Such funds are handed over to the state. In NE, like in many states, there is a government website where you can search by your name, find them, and claim them (with proof of your identity, etc.):
https://treasurer.nebraska.gov/up/

For sure, the bank cannot just take the money. It is sitting somewhere, the bank just closed the account, meaning they are technically not managing your money anymore.

Comment: You may also need to provide proof that you lived at the address associated with the account at the time.  Such is the case for some unclaimed funds I have been denied by my state from a small insurance payout awarded when I was in a college apartment (and not yet responsible enough to keep a copy of the lease or other related documents after moving out).